# How to set fields on a second form using a redirect action of the same page

Tags: acumatica

I'm using a grid with checkmarks that when a Row is pressed by the checkmark field a second form is automatically filled with two fields that belongs to a different DAC, the problem starts when the redirect action is pressed, it should set all the fields that the user previously entered but is always setting the 2 fields of the first Row, 
How I can set the fields of the Last Row that was selected?

[image: This is my page]

This is the code of the Copy Action:

```
public PXAction<SOProcessCustomerFilter> CopyDescription;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Copy", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    public virtual void copyDescription()
    {
        SOProcessCustomerFilter sOProcessCustomerFilterRow = SOProcessCustomerRecord.Current;
        InternalNotesHelper internalNotesHelperRow = NotesRecord.Current;
        FSServiceOrder fSServiceOrderRow = SOProcessDetails.Current;
        FSServiceOrderTGExt fSServiceOrderExtRow = PXCache<FSServiceOrder>.GetExtension<FSServiceOrderTGExt>(fSServiceOrderRow);
        bool serviceOrderSelected = false;
        bool SODescriptionDash = fSServiceOrderRow.DocDesc.Contains("-");
        string[] SODescription = fSServiceOrderRow.DocDesc.Split('-');
        string internalNotes = "";
        string internalNotesSO = "";

        if (sOProcessCustomerFilterRow != null)
        {
            PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate ()
            {
                ServiceOrderEntry serviceOrderGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<ServiceOrderEntry>();

                using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
                {
                    if (fSServiceOrderExtRow != null)
                    {
                        serviceOrderGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Current = serviceOrderGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Search<FSServiceOrder.refNbr>(fSServiceOrderRow.RefNbr, fSServiceOrderRow.SrvOrdType);

                        if (serviceOrderGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Current != null)
                        {
                            if (fSServiceOrderExtRow.SelectExt == true)
                            {
                                if (SODescriptionDash == true)
                                {
                                    if (SODescription.Length <= 2)
                                    {
                                        internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes = " - " + SODescription[1] + "\r\n" + internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 1; i < SODescription.Length; i++)
                                        {
                                            internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes += " - " + SODescription[i];
                                        }
                                        internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes = internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes;
                                    }
                                    fSServiceOrderExtRow.UsrJobDescription = internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotes;
                                    fSServiceOrderExtRow.UsrInternalNotes = internalNotesHelperRow.InternalNotesSO;
                                    internalNotes = fSServiceOrderExtRow.UsrJobDescription;
                                    internalNotesSO = fSServiceOrderExtRow.UsrInternalNotes;
                                    fSServiceOrderExtRow.UsrModified = true;
                                    serviceOrderGraph.ServiceOrderRecords.Update(fSServiceOrderRow);
                                    serviceOrderGraph.Actions.PressSave();

                                    fSServiceOrderExtRow.ModifiedNotes = false;
                                    TGSOProcessMaint tGSOProcessGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<TGSOProcessMaint>();
                                    if (sOProcessCustomerFilterRow != null)
                                    {
                                        tGSOProcessGraph.SOProcessCustomerRecord.Current.CustomerID = sOProcessCustomerFilterRow.CustomerID;
                                        tGSOProcessGraph.SOProcessCustomerRecord.Current.MSPType = sOProcessCustomerFilterRow.MSPType;
                                        if (sOProcessCustomerFilterRow.ManagerInt != null)
                                        {
                                            tGSOProcessGraph.SOProcessCustomerRecord.Current.ManagerInt = sOProcessCustomerFilterRow.ManagerInt;
                                        }
                                        foreach (FSServiceOrder fSServiceOrderrow in SOProcessDetails.Select())
                                        {
                                            FSServiceOrderTGExt fSServiceOrderRowExt = PXCache<FSServiceOrder>.GetExtension<FSServiceOrderTGExt>(fSServiceOrderrow);
                                            fSServiceOrderExtRow.SelectExt = fSServiceOrderRowExt.SelectExt;
                                            tGSOProcessGraph.SOProcessDetails.Update(fSServiceOrderrow);

                                        }
                                        throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(tGSOProcessGraph, false, "Page") { Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Same };
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw new PXException("Description doesn't contain '-'");
                                }
                            }
                            serviceOrderSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!serviceOrderSelected)
                    {
                        throw new PXException("No Service Order Selected");
                    }

                    ts.Complete();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the second form and maybe add your code to the questions ?

Comment: The form is the one at the bottom of the picture with Job Description and Internal Notes fields